# How well does telephone delay correlate to geographic distance?

Tags: delay, telephone

I have a friend who lives on the other side of the world, and every time we speak over the phone, there's roughly a second of delay between one of us saying something and the other hearing it. I've tested this by having her put her phone on speaker so my own voice is detected and returned back to me over her phone as feedback, and the delay over that particular distance is quite consistent.

While surely there are a number of other factors contributing to phone delay beyond propagation time, many of these factors are constant regardless of distance. So if the distance between us were halved, would the delay be as well?

Comment: I don't think these correlate well. Today, in the era of IP telephony some segments of the network might be IP routed. And the latency will very depend on the link speeds and hop numbers.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, speakerphones switch between listen and transmit by using line and microphone signal levels and this means that if your friend's phone is amplying the received signal of you speaking then it won't be simultaneously transmitted back down the line to you. This undermines what you think might be happening.

Comment: @Andyaka you can test this yourself if you like, whether or not it's the result of a technical failure on the part of the telephone system is immaterial, you can provably use many a modern phone on speakerphone to return your voice to you

Comment: I designed a speakerphone many years ago and it was telecom approved and I can assure you that reflecting back a signal coming down the wires would have caused a massive failing in return loss and it would never have been telecom approved.

Comment: @Andyaka The regulations are irrelevant, try experimental evidence. Call a friend or family member with their phone on speaker at maximum volume. Depending on the system you should hear your voice reflected back to you

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that the telephone delay was due to the signal being sent through a geosynchronous satellite. These are a long way up and the signal took that long to get there and back.

Today delays through routing devices are more likely to be the cause of the pause.

Half way round the earth is about 20 million meters with light or signal travelling at 300 million m/s direct transmission delay would only be about .066 seconds. Of course your wiring distance may be a little different,

Answer (score 1):

40,075 km is the circumference of the earth. ( 4e7 meters )

Assuming 2 second delay around the earth's surface in the shortest path implies a minimum velocity of 2e7 [m/s] or about 10% of c thru most controlled impedance submarine and above ground cables (2e8 m/s), or the  equivalent distance traveled is actually 10x more and may include Satellite Hops and TCPIP router zigzags.

Considering the lowest cost now is VOIP via TCPIP, I suspect your phone service provider is routed in a spider web of global routers.

Comment: It isn't the routing paths that introduce the delays these days, its the cheap signal/protocol conversion hardware

Comment: conversion hardware with 1 second buffer time?  even my Magicjack latency is only xx milliseconds

Comment: try 5 hops with 200ms each? or 10 hops with 100ms? or a mix of all kinds of things...

Comment: Latency by buffering is generally minimized at 8kHz sample rate. regardless of how many IP hops on magic jack. If I call a cell phone beside me with VOIP Magicjack there is no significant latency.

Comment: You might make the common mistake of thinking that everyone uses the same (quality of) technology that you have around you. There are countless ways of how the hops may introduce latency. It is not just the buffering at the sender, it can be at any hop, whether due to crappy implementation or failures of various kinds.

Comment: We have no idea what kind of phone anyone has.  It could be an Iridium Phone he has for all we know. But in general my comments are true for VOIP.

Comment: When outside with one of my wifi voip phones it develops ever increasing latency because tcp keeps having to resend more and more lots packets. You can have the same situation along the path.

Comment: Ah the good old days of high quality telecom are gone with low latency , high reliability and >60dB SNR with compression. Now mobile low SNR and high distortion are the norm. https://fthmb.tqn.com/k858CDGNkIKgWC75kK_Q_bS_bUQ=/768x0/filters:no_upscale()/server_room_200241881-001-56a1adb35f9b58b7d0c1a1f2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In the same way there are delays with an internet connection, satellite transmissions, etc, the current technology has these limitations.

The data being sent over the phone is processed and routed through several different devices, from several different operators, which prevents this communication from being instantaneous.

The bigger the distance, the more "nodes" it passes through, so the higher the delay. The devices I'm referring to are not necessarily on Earth, they can be satellites also.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in a (fixed) telephone company, and electrical signals are almost instantly. However, signals are routed through devices which each takes some processing time. Like signals (from different calls) are multiplexed, demultiplexed, error corrected, enhanced etc. Also it is likely one signal is handled by different hubs/points where signals are received/transmitted each adding their processing time.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily break the correlation. If, for example, there's a device that adds 10ms of delay on average every 100 miles or so, the correlation holds even though transmission speed is no longer the deciding factor.

Comment: No of course these delays are ' added' and not relevant of the length of the cables.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, almost all telephone calls travel through the internet, so geographical distance does not play such an important role in signal propagation time.

In this case, the propagation time of the information is mainly related to the amount of [Hops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop_(networking)) in the network between source and destination and the [bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing)) of each one of them.

Wikipedia:

> Almost all In computer networking, a hop is one portion of the path
>   between source and destination. Data packets pass through bridges,
>   routers and gateways as they travel between source and destination.
>   Each time packets are passed to the next network device, a hop occurs.
>   The hop count refers to the number of intermediate devices through
>   which data must pass between source and destination.
>
> Since store and forward and other latencies are incurred through each
>   hop, a large number of hops between source and destination implies
>   lower real-time performance.